# Gluing topological maps and considering the preimage

Tags: general-topology

Given topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ and an open cover $\{W_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $X$. Suppose for each $i$ there exists a continuous map $f_i\colon W_i\to Y$ such that the restrictions of $f_i$ and $f_j$ to $W_i\cap W_j$ coincide. Then there exists a continuous map $f\colon X\to Y$ with the restriction of $f$ to $W_i$ is equal to $f_i$ for each $i$.

If I further suppose that for each $i$, $f_i$ defines a homeomorphism $W_i\cong U_i$ for some (open) subset $U_i$ of $Y$, is it true that for each pair $i,j \in I$, $f^{-1}(U_i\cap U_j)=W_i\cap W_j$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the case. Let $X=\{1,2\}$ and $Y=\{1\}$ under the discrete topology. Let $U_i=Y$ and $W_i=\{i\}$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$. Clearly the collection $\{f_1,f_2\}$ satisfies the given conditions, and each $f_i\colon W_i\rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism, but $f^{-1}(Y\cap Y)=f^{-1}(Y)=\{1,2\}\neq W_1\cap W_2=\emptyset$.